# Aggregate mapped values in pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, join, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [["x","y"]], "b": [2]})
df2= pd.DataFrame({"a": ["x","y"], "b":[2,2], "c": [3,4]})
```

where `df.a` has list entries:

```
    a           b   
0   ["x","y"]   2
```

and `df2` maps those list elements (as well as entries of other columns) to a column c:

```
    a       b   c
0   "x"     2   3
1   "y"     2   4
```

I want to left join `df, df2` such that I end up with:

```
    a           b   c
0   ["x","y"]   2   7
```

where the aggregation (in this case sum) is taken across value c mapped from keys a, b.

Comment: Just do it: `df['c'] = sum(df2['c'])`

Comment: no the aggregation has to be done after the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thinking is to first create a unique key in df1 such that it preserves the grouping of the lists in column a, allowing you to use df.explode in pandas > 0.25.  I've also added one additional row to test out how it would work:

```
df1['key'] = (df1.a != df1.a.shift()).cumsum()
df1 = df1.explode('a')
df = df1.merge(df2)
df = df.groupby('key').agg({'a': list, 'b': 'first', 'c': sum}).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
        a  b   c
0  [x, y]  2   7
1     [z]  3  10
```

Comment: thanks! that worked with `df1['key']=df1.index` since column a isn't unique.